# MySQl : How do I use Count on a Sub-Query?

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I've got a MySQL statement that selects a name and also makes a ranking.

```
  SELECT t.name,                        
         (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM my_table1 z
           WHERE z.type LIKE '%Blue%' 
             AND t.type  LIKE '%Blue%'
             AND (z.score1+ z.score2 + z.score3 + z.score4) >= (t.score1+ t.score2 + t.score3 + t.score4)) AS  rank                     
    FROM my_table1 t, my_table2 d
   WHERE d.name = t.name
     AND t.status != 'unknown'
     AND t.type = 'Blue'
     AND d.area_served = '$area_id'                 
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

But, I also need to know out of how many the rank is calculated. So for example, ranked #4 out of X.

How do I count the total number of rows in the ranking sub-query? I need the count for this bit:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM my_table1 z
    WHERE z.type LIKE '%Blue%' AND  t.type  LIKE '%Blue%'
    AND (z.score1+ z.score2 + z.score3 + z.score4) >= (t.score1+ t.score2 + t.score3 + t.score4)) AS  rank
```

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add one more subquery - it will be the same as the existing, but without `AND (z.score1+ z.score2 + z.score3 + z.score4) >= (t.score1+ t.score2 + t.score3 + t.score4)` condition:

```
 SELECT t.name,                        
     (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM my_table1 z
       WHERE z.type LIKE '%Blue%' 
         AND t.type  LIKE '%Blue%'
         AND (z.score1+ z.score2 + z.score3 + z.score4) >= (t.score1+ t.score2 + t.score3 + t.score4)) AS  rank,
      // new subquery
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM my_table1 z
       WHERE z.type LIKE '%Blue%' 
         AND t.type  LIKE '%Blue%') as max_rank
FROM my_table1 t, my_table2 d   
WHERE d.name = t.name
 AND t.status != 'unknown'
 AND t.type = 'Blue'
 AND d.area_served = '$area_id'                 
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same subselect without the score comparison:

```
SELECT t.name,                        
         (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM my_table1 z
           WHERE z.type LIKE '%Blue%' 
             AND t.type  LIKE '%Blue%'
             AND (z.score1+ z.score2 + z.score3 + z.score4) >= (t.score1+ t.score2 + t.score3 + t.score4)) AS  rank,                 
         (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM my_table1 z
           WHERE z.type LIKE '%Blue%' 
             AND t.type  LIKE '%Blue%') AS rankOutOf
    FROM my_table1 t, my_table2 d
   WHERE d.name = t.name
     AND t.status != 'unknown'
     AND t.type = 'Blue'
     AND d.area_served = '$area_id'
```

The `rankOutOf` column returns the number of candidates considered in the ranking query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand, but I think you should include FOUND_ROWS() in the subquery.

> (SELECT COUNT(*), FOUND_ROWS() FROM
>   my_table1 z WHERE z.type LIKE '%Blue%'
>   AND  t.type  LIKE '%Blue%' AND
>   (z.score1+ z.score2 + z.score3 +
>   z.score4) >= (t.score1+ t.score2 +
>   t.score3 + t.score4)) AS  rank, number

You can find more information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: It cannot work - subquery in `select` clause must not return more than 1 column

Comment: Hi Marek,
Thank you for the idea. I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, I got error #1214 - Operand should contain 1 column. If you have other suggestions, please let me know. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding your question, but I'll take a stab at it.

This part gets you the specific rank number (such as 4):

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM my_table1 z
    WHERE z.type LIKE '%Blue%' AND  t.type  LIKE '%Blue%'
    AND (z.score1+ z.score2 + z.score3 + z.score4) >= (t.score1+ t.score2 + t.score3 + t.score4)) AS  rank
```

So in order to find the total number of rows from that subquery, you should just need to remove your `WHERE` clause. I'm not sure if you need to remove everything in the `WHERE` clause though, maybe just the types, or just the scores?

If you have multiple rows that you want to be grouped together, I would use `GROUP BY` and then use `COUNT` as necessary.